# Did Clark's (Kal El's) glasses increase the power of his heat vision?

Tags: dc, superman, superman-2

In Superman II Lois jumps into the Niagara River to test her theory that Clark is actually Superman. Clark uses heat vision to break a branch off of a tree in hopes that Lois can use it as a life saving flotation device. Did Clark's thick, thick lenses provide assistance to his heat vision? If not, how did his glasses not get melted or destroyed? They were not a part of his original uniform.

Comment: In the original comics, I believe the lenses in the glasses were made from a window of the ship that brought Kal-El to Earth.  Doesn't help with the movie because that ship had no such window :)

Comment: My question is about the movie.

Comment: Understand question is about the movie.  Just offering some general info and I did qualify the comment with "doesn't help with the movie".  It was a comment, not an 'answer'.

Comment: Oh got it. Didn't mean to sound rude. There is a "comic book guy" lurking around here who seems to think that parts in the script which were left out of the film are relevant.

Comment: Depending on what the heat ray vision is exactly, it may not affect glass at all while still being able to cut trees. (Just like sunlight shining into your window will warm up things inside, but it won't warm the window panes.)

Answer (score 2):

It's just a plot hole and there's no real explanation for it, other than one someone could just make up (ie super-focusing micro-heat vision). Something similar happened in the first episode of Lois and Clark. It's best to just ignore it.
And the beauty is, you can if you watch Superman II: The Richard Donner Cut. It's a 2006 recut of Superman II by the original director, who was replaced during filming of the second movie. In this version there is now a similar themed scene in the Daily Planet building at the start of the movie, which covers much of the same ground, so much of the Niagara Falls stuff has been chopped out. It's worth a look, if you haven't seen it already.